# How to fit a KNN and then a linear regression with those neighbors?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, k-nn

How do I fit a KNN to get the $k$ nearest neighbors and then aggregate the those neighbors into a fit using a linear regression (instead of a weighted average) in Scikit-Learn?

I've tried creating a pipeline using `KNeighborsTransformer` and then `LinearRegression` but that doesn't appear to be doing the right thing.

Comment: Curious, why you would do this? Are you going by a research paper ? Please provide details if so.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, it would be great to see your implementation (code) and the error traceback, so we know how we best help!

Comment: @Ryan - are you aware of https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html ?

Comment: Neat idea, whats it for? Does it work well?

Answer (score 1):

`KNeighborsTransformer` only gives you the indices of the nearest neighbors and the distances.  You need to do more work to retrieve the points to fit your linear regression.

Here's a draft that appears to be working:

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin, BaseEstimator, clone
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.utils import check_X_y
import numpy as np

class LocalLinearRegressor(RegressorMixin, BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, n_neighbors=10, linear_model=Lasso()):
        self.n_neighbors = n_neighbors
        self.linear_model = linear_model

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        "Fits the neighbors search."
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
        self._fit_X = X
        self._fit_y = y
        self.neighbor_search = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=self.n_neighbors)
        self.neighbor_search.fit(X)
        self.local_regressors_ = {}
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        """Fits linear regressions on the k nearest training points to predict new values.
        
        We don't fit these linear regressions at fit time because there would be so many.
        However, we do save the regressions as we see them to speed up predictions.
        """
        neighbors = self.neighbor_search.kneighbors(X, return_distance=False)
        ksets, mapper = np.unique(neighbors, return_inverse=True, axis=0)
        for kset in ksets:
            if tuple(kset) in self.local_regressors_:
                continue
            local_X = self._fit_X[kset, :]
            local_y = self._fit_y[kset]
            self.local_regressors_[tuple(kset)] = clone(self.linear_model).fit(local_X, local_y)
        return np.array([
            self.local_regressors_[tuple(ksets[mapper[i]])].predict(X[i, :].reshape(1, -1))[0]
            for i in range(X.shape[0])
        ])
```

And here's [a Colab notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/93516_local_regression.ipynb) showing it in action.